# Cannot overload operator<< for an iterator with a templated function

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I have overloaded `operator<<` for several templated classes, e.g. `map`, `pair` (see below), `list`.
They work nicely and are quite versatile. Whenever I need something more specific, I define other `operator<<` which take precedence.

But I could not do the same for iterators. I get compile errors. I guess the fact of dealing with `operator<<` is irrelvant, but the point is templating with iterators.

Am I doing something wrong, or what I want to do is not possible?

The code that I have now (after the answer by Brian) is shown below. Note that the errors are briefly noted in each line in the definition of the functiov, and in more detail below the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

typedef pair<string, char> pair_t;
typedef map<pair_t::first_type, pair_t::second_type> map_t;
typedef pair<map_t::iterator, bool> retval_insert_t;

// Templated form of overloading << for a pair
template<typename first_class, class second_class>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const pair<first_class, second_class>& p);
// Templated form of overloading << for an iterator ... does not work
template <class T, class = typename iterator_traits<T>::value_type>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, T iterator);

int main(void) {
    pair_t p2;
    p2 = make_pair(string("Fer"), 'C');

    map_t grade_list;
    retval_insert_t retval = grade_list.insert(p2);
    cout << retval.first << endl;  // Does not work with a templated <<

    return 0;
}

//**********************   Overloaded << functions   ***************************************

// ***** pair
// Templated form of overloading << for a pair
template<class first_class, class second_class>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const pair<first_class, second_class>& p)
{
    os << "(" << p.first << ", " << p.second << ")";  // Compilation error: Ambiguous overload for the first <<
    return os;
}

template <class T, class = typename iterator_traits<T>::value_type>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, T iterator)
{
    os << iterator;  // No compilation error, but segmentation fault
    os << *iterator;  // Compilation error if uncommenting: Cannot bind
    //cout << "Testing" << endl;  // Compilation error if uncommenting: Ambiguous overload for the first <<
    cout << 1 << endl;
    return os;
}
```

`*Cannot bind*` error:

```
g++ -Wall -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -g -g3 -std=gnu++11 -c -o test_iters.o test_iters.cpp
test_iters.cpp: In instantiation of ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, T) [with T = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, char> >; <template-parameter-1-2> = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, char>; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]’:
test_iters.cpp:20:17:   required from here
test_iters.cpp:31:8: error: cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
     os << *iterator;  // Compilation error if uncommenting: Cannot bind
        ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39:0,
                 from test_iters.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:602:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, char>]’
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
     ^
make: *** [test_iters.o] Error 1
```

`*Ambiguous override*` error:

```
g++ -Wall -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -g -g3 -std=gnu++11 -c -o test_iters.o test_iters.cpp  
test_iters.cpp: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, T)’:
test_iters.cpp:32:7: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘const char [8]’)
  cout << "Testing" << endl;  // Compilation error if uncommenting: Ambiguous overload for the first <<
       ^
test_iters.cpp:32:7: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39:0,
                 from test_iters.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:174:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(bool) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
       operator<<(bool __n)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:245:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(const void*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
       operator<<(const void* __p)
       ^
test_iters.cpp:28:10: note: std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, T) [with T = const char*; <template-parameter-1-2> = char; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]
 ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, T iterator)
          ^
...
```

---

**Old code** is (only for documentation purposes):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

typedef pair<string, char> pair_t;
typedef map<pair_t::first_type, pair_t::second_type> map_t;
typedef pair<map_t::iterator, bool> retval_insert_t;

// ***** pair
// Templated form of overloading << for a pair
template<typename first_class, class second_class>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const pair<first_class, second_class>& p);
// ***** iterator
// Templated form of overloading << for a const_iterator
template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, typename T::const_iterator it);
// Templated form of overloading << for an iterator ... does not work
template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, typename T::iterator it);
// Explicit form of overloading << for an iterator
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, map_t::iterator it);  // Compile error if commenting this line
// ***** return value of insert (a map)
// Explicit form of overloading << for the return value of insert
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const retval_insert_t& retval);


int main(void) {
    pair_t p2;
    p2 = make_pair(string("Fer"), 'C');

    map_t grade_list;
    retval_insert_t retval = grade_list.insert(p2);
    cout << retval.first << endl;  // Does not work with a templated operator<<

    return 0;
}

//**********************   Overloaded << functions   ***************************************
//************************  Explicit and templated  ****************************************

// ***** pair
// Templated form of overloading << for a pair
template<class first_class, class second_class>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const pair<first_class, second_class>& p)
{
    os << "(" << p.first << ", " << p.second << ")";
    return os;
}

// ***** iterator
// Templated form of overloading << for a const_iterator
template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, typename T::const_iterator it)
{
    os << *it;
    return os;
}
// Templated form of overloading << for an iterator ... does not work
template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, typename T::iterator it)
{
    os << *it;
    return os;
}
// Explicit form of overloading << for an iterator
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, map_t::iterator it)
{
    os << *it;
    return os;
}

// ***** return value of insert (a map)
// Explicit form of overloading << for the return value of insert
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const retval_insert_t& retval)
{
    os << "retval : <" << retval.first << ", " << retval.second << ">";
    return os;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `T` in `typename T::iterator` is a non-deduced context, so the compiler cannot figure out what `T` is supposed to be when you try to invoke `operator<<` for an iterator type.

One way of writing an overload that works for iterators is using SFINAE to detect whether a given type is an iterator or not:

```
template <class T, class = typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, T iterator);
//                                         ^ This T can be deduced
```

Comment: @sancho.s Please post a complete, self-contained, minimal example. Remove all code not necessary to reproduce the error.

Comment: @sancho.s If you do `os << iterator` inside your `operator<<` then it recursively calls itself until a stack overflow happens. If you do `os << *iterator` then it doesn't compile because there is no overload that prints a pair. You would have to write one.

Comment: You are right. In the frenzy of putting together a minimalistic version I removed the original template for printing a pair. I have reinstated it, but there remain ambiguities at  `cout << "string"` in two lines (indicated in the code). If I comment both the declaration and definition of the function you suggested, the ambiguity is gone. I do not know what I am missing.

Comment: @sancho.s Ah, that's because `operator<<` for a string literal could either be the standard one you get from `#include <iostream>` or it could be the custom `operator<<` for iterators here (since `const char*` is a valid iterator type). You'd probably want to use SFINAE to disable the latter for `char*` and `const char*`.

Comment: I suspected this, and I was checking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192694/templatized-ostream-overload-ambiguity-error-basic-ostreamchar-vs-const-char but I am not familiar with that. In the meantime, and given you probably know that, could you please show me the syntax?